# How can I edit bank account type in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I tried to edit res_partner_data.xml file and I made the following :

```
    <!-- Default bank account description -->

    <record id="bank_normal" model="res.partner.bank.type">

        <field name="name">Normal Bank Account</field>

        <field name="name">Savings Account</field>

        <field name="name">Current Account</field>

        <field name="code">bank</field>

    </record>
```

And

```
data noupdate="false"
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit bank account type"? Do you want to change existing ones or just creating new ones?

Answer (score 0):

you should add bank account with code one by one because in your code `name="name"` taken three times so there may be conflict for selecting name for that record..

Answer (score 0):

```
<record id="bank_normal" model="res.partner.bank.type">
    <field name="name">Normal Bank Account</field>
    <field name="name">Savings Account</field>
    <field name="name">Current Account</field>
    <field name="code">bank</field>
</record>
```

here you have written field name="name" this doesn't make sense, field name should be different. One field name can't be more than one time. Check the model again and recode your XML file.